# Google Sheets - I created a clear cell function but it is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a function that automatically clears a range of cells when a corresponding cell changes from 'Yes' to 'No'.

The range that I want to trigger this function is... i5:i9, i13:i14, i18

The range that I want cleared IF this cell contains 'no' is n5:n9, n13:n14, n18

Both these cells are on the same sheet called 'Wax'.

I have written the following script and assigned it so a button on the sheet but when I press it the script runs and the cells do not delete.

```js
function clearautocraFields(e) {

  var triggerCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Wax').getSheetValues(9,5,13,1);

  if (triggerCell == 'No'){  

  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Wax');
    sheet.getRange('n5:n9').clearcontent();
    sheet.getRange('n13:n14').clearcontent();
    sheet.getRange('n18').clearcontent();
    }

}
```

Please help.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

How about these modifications?

#### Modification points :

- The range of `getSheetValues(9,5,13,1)` is "e9:e21".

  - At first, values of "i5:i18" are retrieved, and then, the unnecessary values are removed.
- The data retrieved by `getSheetValues(9,5,13,1)` is 2 dimensional array.

  - The data retrieved by `getValues()` is also 2 dimensional array.
  - The 2 dimensional array is converted to string using `toString()`, and searched by `indexOf()`
- Please modify `clearcontent()` to `clearContent()`.
- You can use `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Wax')`.

#### Modified script :

```
function clearautocraFields() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Wax');
  var triggerCell = sheet.getRange('i5:i18').getValues();
  triggerCell.splice(5, 3);
  triggerCell.splice(7, 3);
  if (triggerCell.toString().indexOf('No') != -1) {
    sheet.getRange('n5:n9').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('n13:n14').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('n18').clearContent();
  }
}
```

#### References :

- [getSheetValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetValues(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent())

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify.

### Edit :

In this sample script, when `No` is found in the range of "i5:i9, i13:i14, i18", the value of the column "n" with the same row is cleared.

```
function clearautocraFields() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var triggerCell = sheet.getRange('i5:i18').getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<triggerCell.length; i++) {
    var index = i + 5;
    triggerCell[i][1] = "n" + index;
  }
  triggerCell.splice(5, 3);
  triggerCell.splice(7, 3);
  for (var i in triggerCell) {
    if (triggerCell[i][0] == 'No') {
      sheet.getRange(triggerCell[i][1]).clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey I was thinking about this last night and I think I did miss something. I need the script to work where if cell i5 has the value "no" then it clears the specific cell n5, same for i6 and n6 etc. I assume the current script will clear all contents if the cells in the range i5:i9 have the value "no".

Comment: @Tim Hull I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Tim Did my answer work? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study.